# elimination werror in config file in order to make Xen

Tags: gcc, makefile, config, xen

I want to get rid of werror problem [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable] I remove the -Werror from the following command in my config file but I still got same error? anyone knows what is the problem?

```
HOSTCC     = gcc
HOSTCFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable to HOSTCFLAGS line